# MS Word find and replace can't find ^t^p

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

I have an odd situation. I am attempting some major reformatting of a document so I can pull it into a spreadsheet. I'm working in Word 2013 on Windows 8.
What I am trying to do is a find and replace (F&R) of a tab and paragraph to just a tab.

Easy... ^t^p to ^t ... nope, nothing found.

I can get the F&R to see the ^t or ^p individually but not the two together. That implies there's something I can't see in between them. I have all the hidden characters showing and there is nothing visible between them. I've used the "Any character" in the search, and tried a wild card in the search. Still no luck. I've also double checked the find field to confirm there is no formatting selected and all the extra options are off (except the wild card option for that particular search).

It's going to take me days to clean this doc up if I can't get the F&R working. If anyone can think of something I haven't tried, I'd be thrilled to give it a shot.

**I've uploaded an [example doc here](http://www.pwwebhost.com/cic/junk/findandreplace-sample.docx).**

Thanks, Pennopoly

---

**[Addendum #1]** After a little more playing, I've made a little progress. I cut and pasted the document into a new file and stripped out the formatting. The F&R works in the new file (Yay!). Unfortunately, I lose all the doc formatting, some of which I need to keep (Boo!).

Comment: What if you change ^t to, let's say, TTT, then ^p to PPP - does it find TTTPPP string? If it does then change it to ^t and then change back TTT and PPP.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in Notepad++ or a similar text editor. Replace *only* the characters you need to. Note: in NP++, \t is tab, \r is carriage return and \n is newline, so search on **\t\r\n** and replace with **\t**. This should not remove *all* formatting, only the spurious line breaks.

Set *Extended* search to use this notation. You might find that different characters are used for the end-of-paragraph symbol, e.g. just \n or just \r or \n\r, depending on the source of the document.

[image: Search and replace in Notepad++]

Comment: Thanks DrMoishe Pippik, I gave that a try. I am able to do the find and replace in Notepad++, however, similar to my Addendum #1 above, I lose the formatting. Redoing the formatting is better time-wise than removing all the paragraph breaks manually, but it'll still be very time consuming.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't of help.

Comment: Don't be sorry. I really appreciate that you took the time to make the suggestion.